# How to find the twenty most frequently occurring words as efficiently as possible to given a file in python

Tags: hashmap

- Python data structures should not be used
- For time & space complexity that would be O(n) in time and space complexity, but since there may be lots of words we cannot assume that we can store everything in memory. Worst case time complexity should be reduced, At present it is O(N^4)
- Number of words to be displayed and order of display should be provided as configurable option.

Comment: "Python data structures should not be used" so you mean no hashmap/dictionary?

Comment: Yes @PaoloTormon